# Sort a list of candidates according to a metric - Python?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list of 2-D points

```
candidates = [(x1, y1), (x2, y2), (x3, y3), ...]
```

and a reference point `ref = (x0, y0)`.

I now wish to sort the list `candidates` according to their euclidean distances from the reference point `ref`, in ascending order.

What is **the most Pythonic way** of doing so?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Euclidean distance between two points `(x1, y1)` and `(x2, y2)` is given by:

```
sqrt((x1 - y1)^2 + (x2 - y2)^2))
```

To sort the list, you can use the formula, and also you can skip the `sqrt` part, as you are just doing comparison, and not calculating the actual distance. i.e:

```
if x > y then sqrt(x) > sqrt(y)
```

So, following would work:

```
ref = (x0, y0)
candidates = [(x1, y1), (x2, y2), (x3, y3), ...]

candidates.sort(key=lambda x: (x[0] - ref[0]) ** 2 + (x[1] - ref[1]) ** 2)
```

Answer (score 8):

Write a function to calculate euclidean distance and use that function with the `key` parameter of the `list.sort` function.

```
ref = (x0, y0)
def euclidean(coords):
    xx, yy = ref
    x, y = coords
    return ((x-xx)**2 + (y-yy)**2)**0.5

candidates = [(x1, y1), (x2, y2), (x3, y3), ...]
candidates.sort(key=euclidean)
```

Comment: I would use `math.sqrt(x)` instead of `x**.5`, it's about 30 % faster. Similarly, `x*x - 2*x*xx + xx*xx` is faster than `(x-xx)**2`.

Comment: @TimPietzcker I agree `math.sqrt(x)` is more readable, but a function call is always going to be slower than `**.5`.

Comment: Straight-forward and clear. But I wonder if it is possible to make it one-liner?

Comment: @perfectionm1ng Use a lambda for that.

Comment: Nope. Result of `timeit.timeit(setup="from math import sqrt", stmt="[sqrt(x)  for x in range(100,200)]")` is 23 seconds on my machine, whereas `timeit.timeit(stmt="[x**.5  for x in range(100,200)]")` takes 32 seconds.

Comment: @perfectionm1ng: One-liners are rarely the solution, especially not in Python.

Comment: Well, I would avoid doing `sqrt` or `** 0.5`. Not needed here.

Comment: @TimPietzcker  Is there any general explanation for this statement? :)

Comment: @perfectionm1ng: if `x` is greater than `y` (for both positive `x` and `y`), then `sqrt(x)` will always be greater than `sqrt(y)`.

Comment: @TimPietzcker [facepalm] sorry, I should've made myself clear! By *this statement*, I mean *One-liners are rarely the solution, especially not in Python.*

Comment: @perfectionm1ng: Type `import this` at the Python console, and you'll see. On a more general note, human-readability trumps cleverness any day. The compiler doesn't care how verbosely you write your script.

Answer (score 2):

The `key` argument of `list.sort()` will allow you to pass a function that will be used to derive the sort key of each element.

```
candidates.sort(key=lambda x: distance(ref, x))
```